# adding new data to an existing object in the array

Tags: php

This is my object data array

```
var_dump(last_data[0]);
```

Result :

```
object(stdClass)#533 (1) {
  ["nama_item"]=>
  string(8) "Surya 12"
}
```

how do I add the data object array as below
`last_data[0]`

```
object(stdClass)#533 (1) {
  ["nama_item"]=>
  string(8) "Surya 12",
  ["price"]=> 12000
}
```

I've tried this way `$data[0]["price"] => 12000;`

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you trying to change the `price` in the array, trying to add a new `price` or what?

Comment: trying to add new price for "nama_item":"surya 12"